# Jest: mock object used inside tested function

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I would like to mock an object used inside called tested function. All I have found I another tickets was calling function in tested function, but I need to replace certain object that is used there. Is something like that possible in Jest?

**util.test.js**

```
describe('testname', function () {
    it('import test', function () {
      Utils.generateRandomPoints(10); // inside this function, I'd like to mock used object
    });
});
```

**utils.js**

```
export function generateRandomPoints(arrayLength) {    
    const result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        // instead of "new Point" I'd like to use "new MockedPoint" for testing.
        result.push(new Point(i)); 
    }
    
    return result;
};
```

Comment: Assuming `Point` comes from a module, I think you can use [`jest.mock()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules).

Answer (score 0):

```
const MockPoint = jest.fn();
jest.mock('path/to/Point', () => ({
  Point: jest.fn().mockImplementation(MockPoint),
}));
```

and you can add whatever functionality to MockPoint, e.g.

```
const MockPoint = jest.fn((props) => console.log(props));
```